# How to get checkbox checked value and run code on if checked value is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have input with an id and i need to add a class to the id when it is checked(true) and remove when it is false.

```
<input id="<?= $ec['id']?>" type="checkbox" value="<?= $ec['id']?>" class="category" onclick="handleClick(this)" >

 <script>
            function handleClick(cb) {
                var id= cb.id;var checked = cb.checked ;
                console.log("id is " + id + cb.checked);

                if ($('#id').is(':checked')) {
                    console.log("inside if");
                }

            }
 </script>
```

Comment: `.addClass` and `.removeClass` will help!

Comment: use the change() to determine if the checkbox is checked or not

Answer (score 0):

> Use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) with `state`

```js
function handleClick(cb) {
  $(cb).toggleClass('checked', cb.checked);
}
```

```css
.checked {
  border: solid #ff0000 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="100" class="category" onclick="handleClick(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function handleClick(cb) {
   var id= cb.id;
   var checked = cb.checked ;
   console.log("id is " + id + cb.checked);

   if(cb.checked) {
      $(cb).addClass('check');
   }
   else {
      $(cb).removeClass('check');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleClick(cb) 
{
   $(cb).prop('checked') ? $(cb).addClass('checkboxSelected') : $(cb).removeClass('checkboxSelected'); 
}
```